# ReactJS and Firebase Quota Reached Very Fast with Small Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Can someone help with explaining how I would reach my 50k daily reads with a small amount of data stored? My database consists of categories and items, and I had like 4 categories, and maybe 5 items stored, and in less than a few hours it reached 50k read.

I'm have custom hooks like this:

```
export const useItems = (selectedCategory) => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [archivedItems, setArchivedItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let unsubscribe = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("items")
      .where("userId", "==", "1");

    unsubscribe =
      selectedCategory && !collatedItemsExist(selectedCategory)
        ? (unsubscribe = unsubscribe.where(
            "categoryId",
            "==",
            selectedCategory
          ))
        : selectedCategory === "INBOX" || selectedCategory === 0
        ? (unsubscribe = unsubscribe.where("date", "==", ""))
        : unsubscribe;

    unsubscribe = unsubscribe.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      const newItems = snapshot.docs.map((item) => ({
        id: item.id,
        ...item.data(),
      }));

      setItems(newItems.filter((item) => item.archived !== true));
      setArchivedItems(newItems.filter((item) => item.archived !== false));
    });

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, [selectedCategory]);
  return { items, archivedItems };
};

export const useCategories = () => {
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("categories")
      .where("userId", "==", "1")
      .orderBy("categoryId")
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        const allCategories = snapshot.docs.map((category) => ({
          ...category.data(),
          docId: category.id,
        }));

        if (JSON.stringify(allCategories) !== JSON.stringify(categories)) {
          setCategories(allCategories);
        }
      });
  }, [categories]);

  return { categories, setCategories };
};
```

Then in my Items.jsx page I have this:

```
export const Items = () => {
  const { selectedCategory } = useSelectedCategoryValue();
  const { categories } = useCategoriesValue();
  const { items } = useItems(selectedCategory);

  let categoryName = "";

  if (categories && selectedCategory && !collatedItemsExist(selectedCategory)) {
    categoryName = getTitle(categories, selectedCategory).name;
  }

  if (collatedItemsExist(selectedCategory) && selectedCategory) {
    categoryName = getCollatedTitle(collatedItems, selectedCategory).name;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = `${categoryName}`;
  });

  return (
    <div className="tasks" data-testid="tasks">
      <h2 data-testid="project-name">{categoryName}</h2>

      <ul className="tasks__list">
        {items.map((item, i) => (
          <li key={`${item}-${i}`}>
            <div className="flex tasks-list-price-item">
              <span>{item.item}</span>
              <span>{item.price}</span>
            </div>
            <div>
              <span>{item.description}</span>
            </div>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <AddItem />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Is it because useEffect runs multiple times where it continuously reads all the data? Is there a way to optimize the reading so it doesn't read the same data over and over again? What are some of the best practices that I should look into?

Should I use something else like mongodb instead of firebase?

Comment: Have you tried adding logging to see what is being invoked and when?  That should tell you pretty quickly when something causes a read.

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson - hmmm yeah you're right, something is wrong with my useEffect, it just keeps running and running. I'll have to debug this. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson I'm not sure why what I have in useEffect is causing it to rerender. Was there something wrong that I did?

Comment: You have the variable selectedCategory in your useEffect dependency array, so any time that variable changes it will run the hook again. Is it possible that's why?

Comment: @TaylorBurke So I was explaining the reason in the answer below... The JSON.stringify check I have, for some reason doesn't match. The `setCategories` in my `useCategories` hook doesn't match perfectly, and there's like 1 or 2 properties that got switched around. I used lodash to get them to work, but I think there's a new issue where it executes twice instead of just once

Comment: @hellomello I apologize because I haven't had time to really look at your code in depth. But maybe it's possible that the hook is running twice because it is running once when the component initially renders and then again when the categories variable is updated? As I said, I haven't had a chance to really look at your code so this is just a hunch more than anything. Abumalick seems to have a good grasp on the situation, and I would recommend reading the documentation he links to if you haven't already.

Comment: @TaylorBurke no need to apologize! i appreciate the help tho! Yeah I'll continue to look at the documentation and maybe if I still need help, present a new question on stackoverflow. Thank you for the help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Understand useEffect dependencies

It is very important to understand the second argument of `useEffect`. Here is a quote of the official documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect

> The default behavior for effects is to fire the effect after every completed render. That way an effect is always recreated if one of its dependencies changes.
>
> However, this may be overkill in some cases, like the subscription example from the previous section. We don’t need to create a new subscription on every update, only if the source prop has changed.
>
> To implement this, pass a second argument to useEffect that is the array of values that the effect depends on. Our updated example now looks like this:

```js
useEffect(
  () => {
    const subscription = props.source.subscribe();
    return () => {
      subscription.unsubscribe();
    };
  },
  [props.source],
);
```

The effect will be fired once after the first render, **and** after each render where the dependency (`props.source`) changes.

### Current case analysis

```js
useEffect(() => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("categories")
      .where("userId", "==", "1")
      .orderBy("categoryId")
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        const allCategories = snapshot.docs.map((category) => ({
          ...category.data(),
          docId: category.id,
        }));

        if (JSON.stringify(allCategories) !== JSON.stringify(categories)) {
          setCategories(allCategories);
        }
      });
  }, [categories]);
```

What happens here?

- After the first render, the effect is fired, and start downloading the categories from firebase.
- After the categories are fetched it compares the downloaded categories with the current state that is empty, so the condition is true and it saves the downloaded categories in the state.
- The state (variable `categories`) got updated (updating the state in React triggers a new `render`), a new render is triggered with the updated `categories` state
- As `categories` state is a dependency of the effect, the effect is fired after the render, it downloads the categories from firebase again.
- The if statement checks if the categories from the state are the same than the newly downloaded categories. If the data is different, it saves to the state and will fire the effect again after the rerender. If the data is the same it stops here.

### Conclusion

As you pointed in the comments, the problem was that your condition was never false, so it was fetching the categories over and over again until the quota was reached.

You probably want to fetch the categories only one time, you don't need to download it even two times. So the best solution is to remove the `categories` dependency from the dependency array. Also if you fetch the categories only one time, you don't need the condition that is comparing the current state with the downloaded categories.

So my advice would be to change the code to this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("categories")
      .where("userId", "==", "1")
      .orderBy("categoryId")
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        const allCategories = snapshot.docs.map((category) => ({
          ...category.data(),
          docId: category.id,
        }));
        setCategories(allCategories);
        
      });
  }, []);
```

If you need to refetch the categories from the api again for some reason, you can do it by setting the correct dependency in the dependency array.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. So I was following a tutorial on this, and they were saying this checks the category changes, cause there's a list of categories, and I'm able to add more categories and switch between the category list.

Comment: Your implementation may be different from the tutorial. It is important to understand what is the array of dependency of useEffect: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect 

Does this answer your question? If it is the case, please select it as the chosen answer. If not please develop more so I can try to improve my answer.

Comment: Hi! thanks for your response. So I think I know why I'm having trouble, but I'm not sure why its happening... So I'm having that check because its supposed to prevent the continuous setCategories, however, the `allCategories` and `categories` (after it gets set) doesn't match. Sometimes only 1 property gets switched around, and I don't know why it does that

Comment: So I did this: `if (!_.isEqual(_.sortBy(allCategories), _.sortBy(categories))) {setCategories(allCategories)}` instead, is this the proper way? seems to work

Comment: No it will still trigger two times if you keep the [categories] dependency. Do you want to fetch the categories only one time? When do you want to refetch categories?

Comment: The problem with this is that it doesn't update when I add new categories in a component I have. I think that's why I need to have categories in the second argument. This way it will check if there's anything new. That is what I was thinking, or am I thinking wrong? But you are correct, it does execute twice, which sucks! Really appreciate you helping me!

Comment: You can move this fetch categories logic to a useCallback and trigger this callback at two places: 1 in this useEffect for the initial fetch, 2 after you successfully created the new category in firebase